# Procemiento Almacenado MySql error en la llamada

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

les saludo, y al mismo tiempo les pido este favor.

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en MySql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referido de la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá tengo el detalle de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando creo el Procedimiento almacenado, me lo crea bien, sin embargo cuando quiero introducir datos mediante el procedimiento, me genera error. Acá la llamada al procedimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe señalar, que los ultimos dos datos (los numeros) los he introducido con y sin comillas (simples y dobles) y aún así me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece extraño (tal vez mis conocimientos son demasiado poco) que me de error de ese tipo, pues estoy introduciendo un dato.

Favor si me pudiesen ayudar les agradecería enormemente.

Comment: Mándale `'Buena'` con comillas simples, y los datos numéricos sin nada a ver que tal. Las fechas como las tienes, con comillas simples. Para este caso en vez de las imágenes es mejor que compartas el texto de tu código y el texto del mensaje de error. Las imágenes no sirven de gran cosa, y son difíciles de ver en dispositivos pequeños.

Comment: Otra cosa es que no tienes que usar `@` delante de los nombres de parámetros  en la sentencia de inserción.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sigue sin funcionar, pondré el texto del codigo. 

delimiter $$
create procedure InsertarDetalle3
(
FechaPedido datetime,
FechaDevolucion datetime,
Calificacion varchar(45),
Libros_IdLibro int,
Usuario_idUsuario int
)
begin
insert into detallepedido(FechaPedido, FechaDevolucion, Calificacion, 
Libros_IdLibro, Usuario_idUsuario) values (vFechaPedido, vFechaDevolucion, 
vCalificacion, vLibros_IdLibro, vUsuario_idUsuario);
end $$
delimiter ;

la llamada:

call InsertarDetalle3('2019-01-01','2019-01-02', 'Buena' , 4, 2);

Comment: Es mejor que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/243841/edit) poniendo el texto en ella. ¿Poniéndolo así te da el mismo error? Ponle la palabra `IN` delante de los nombres de parámetros.

Comment: Borré los @ y ejecuté el proc bien, pero al hacer la llamada, me el siguiente error: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`libritos`.`detallepedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_DetallePedido_Libros1` FOREIGN KEY (`Libros_IdLibro`) REFERENCES `libros` (`IdLibro`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Editaré la pregunta entonces, mientras tanto te comento que agregué in delante de los nombres pero me sigue dando el error que recien escribí. De pasada, te agradezco tu ayuda hasta aquí.

Comment: **Ahora funciona**, pero te da **otro error** porque los datos que mandas violan una restricción de integridad referencial: *`a foreign key constraint fails`* Intentas insertar un ID con referencia huérfana en su tabla relacionada. No sé si entiendes bien esto, pero si tienes reglas de integridad referencial significa que no puedes insertar en una tabla relaciona una ID que no exista en la tabla padre.

Comment: Gracias!, tienes toda la razón. ingresé la clave existente de la otra tabla y funcioó perfectamente.

Comment: O sea, si tú mandas un valor `4` para que sea insertado en la columna  `Libros_IdLibro` de la tabla `detallepedido` y hay una restricción de integridad referencial definida, en la tabla padre, que sería `libros` debe existir un registro con `IdLibro` igual a `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estás usando `@` para las parámetros.

Puedes definir tu `PROCEDURE`  así:

```
delimiter $$ 
create procedure InsertarDetalle3 (IN 
    FechaPedido datetime, 
    FechaDevolucion datetime, 
    Calificacion varchar(45), 
    Libros_IdLibro int, 
    Usuario_idUsuario int) 
begin 
    insert into detallepedido (
        FechaPedido, 
        FechaDevolucion, 
        Calificacion, 
        Libros_IdLibro, 
        Usuario_idUsuario
    ) values (
        vFechaPedido, 
        vFechaDevolucion, 
        vCalificacion, 
        vLibros_IdLibro, 
        vUsuario_idUsuario
    ); 
end $$ 
delimiter ;
```

Y en la llamada tienes que se coherente, usando comillas simples para los valores `DATETIME` o `VARCHAR` y nada para los valores numéricos:

```
call InsertarDetalle3('2019-01-01','2019-01-02', 'Buena' , 4, 2);
```

Aunque `IN` es la definición por defecto, es mejor ponerla, para mayor claridad.